# Show the best player depend of Medals achieved Mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a Medals Table Like that :

Have 3 Rows  : id of medals  , Type of medals (0 = Gold , 1 = Silver , 2 = Bronze) and playerId

so I have an example :

```
id  | type |  Playerid
---   ----   ---------
 1     0         1
 2     2         1
 3     0         1
 4     1         2
 5     1         2
 6     0         3
```

*So that's mean :

The player 1 has Two Gold medals and one bronze

The player 1 has 2 silver medals

The player 3 has 1 bronze medal

so I cant to show them in order of who is the best until the last means  :

player 1  because he have the player 1 has 2 gold medals more

player 3 even he has just 1 medal but it is a gold one

player 2 is the last one even he has 2 medals but it is silver medals

so I hope you understand that I don't want to order them by the SUM of medals they have but the category of medals they have

Example : if a player X has 2 gold medals and 1 silver and 0 bronze , but the Player Y has 1  gold and 10 silver and 5 bronze , even that the player X should be the first because he hase the most Gold ones ! .

I hope I gave the right explaining of the problem .

Witing for you suggestions of how make it by a mysql query and php.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, it's fairly simple to order by counts of the categories;

```
SELECT playerid 
FROM medals
GROUP BY playerid
ORDER BY SUM(type=0) DESC, SUM(type=1) DESC, SUM(type=2) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f04/4).

Or, to get all info at once;

```
SELECT playerid, SUM(type=0) Gold, SUM(type=1) Silver, SUM(type=2) Bronze
FROM medals
GROUP BY playerid
ORDER BY Gold DESC, Silver DESC, Bronze DESC
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f04/5).

Comment: Yeah, that was what I mean (:

Comment: Hi , What I should do If need to show number of each medals type achieved as example :

(player1 has 2 golds , 0 silver , 3 bronze)

Comment: @adil Did you try the second query?

Comment: yes I did ! but it give the same result of the first I think I  need the php query to show this counting

Comment: it's work fine it's how me the right ordering but I need to add how many gold ,silver ,bronze medals achieve each player.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to order them by "who has the most gold metals first, then the most silver, then the most bronze"?

If that's correct, you *can* use `SUM()`, but on a per-medal-type level and then order on those fields:

```
SELECT
   PlayerId,
   SUM(type = 0) AS gold,
   SUM(type = 1) AS silver,
   SUM(type = 2) AS bronze
FROM
    Medals
GROUP BY
    PlayerId
ORDER BY
    gold, silver, bronze;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a fairly simple process. Your description was halfway there.

You just need to Order by the sums of each of the medals, in descending order (I.e. 4 golds beats 3 golds; and 4 golds and one silver beat 4 golds and 1 bronze). You also need to group by Playerid so that each row corresponds to a player.

```
SELECT Playerid 
FROM MedalsTable 
GROUP BY Playerid 
ORDER BY SUM(type='0') DESC, SUM(type='1') DESC, SUM(type='2') DESC
```